# Chatter feeds from different records

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I want to use the standard chatter:feed VF component to show posts on multiple records of a custom object I have.
I'm not sure if this is doable or it will only show posts related to a single record which I indicate with the EntityFeed parameter.
Any advise if this can be achieved?

Comment: How about doing a chatter:feed inside an apex:repeat ?

Comment: I guess that UI wise it wouldn't be an acceptable solution

Comment: Did you get answer to your queries. Even i do have similar requirement, Please let me know the way you did it. Thanks.